# How to keep the animation at the end without restarting?

Tags: unity-game-engine

not loop disable/enable but to keep the animation at it's end frame.

the animation pointing is starting by default but when the state getting to the end the animation ending and not playing again. if i make it loop it will start over again when ending but i don't want it to start over again but to stay on the last frame.

[image: pointing state]

The pointing animation make the player pointing with the finger on a target :

[image: pointing target]

i want the animation to stay at this frame or the last frame so the hand and finger will point all the time and not starting over again.

but this way the hand when the state finish playing move back down.

[image: pointing state ended]

I tried to enable loop and then to enable also loop pose but didn't work so i tried to change the root transform rotation , root transform position Y , root transform position x-z to bake into pose but nothing of that worked yet.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution is to set the key frames of the animation to the two frames where you want to keep the animation at when playing it.

In my case it's frames 78-79 : I set the frames 78 as the Start and frame 79 as the End. Loop time and Loop pose both disabled unchecked.

[image: settings frames]